# 'Error' message: 'Property 'from' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, angular2-observables

I am trying to learn reactive programming using RxJS. I was trying to create an observable from an array using **Observable.from()** method, but I am getting an error:

> Property 'from' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'

I scaffolded an Angular application using Angular CLI, so all the dependencies including RxJS package was imported correctly.

In **app.component.ts** I added below import statements:

```
import { Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable'
import 'rxjs/observable/from'
```

And my AppComponent class looks like this:

```
export class AppComponent {

  numbers: number[] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

  callMyObservable() : void {  
    Observable.from(this.numbers);
  }
}
```

But I am getting the above mentioned compile time error.

I am not sure how to make it work.

Comment: Same for other properties like ["Property `'merge'` does not exist..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52803121/rxjs-updated-property-merge-does-not-exist-on-type-typeof-observable)

Comment: And also; ["Property `'debounceTIme'` does not exist...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51917433/angular6-property-debouncetime-does-not-exist-on-type-observableany/51917462)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

If you are using rxjs >=6.0.0 then you no longer use `Observable.from`. Instead `from` is a standalone function.

```ts
import { Observable, from} from 'rxjs';

//old way
var o = Observable.from([1, 2, 3, 4]);

//new way
var o = from([1, 2, 3, 4]);
```

I hope this is helpful since it took me a while to figure this out.

Comment: Accepted answers don't stand the test of time like they used to!  Nice one

Comment: @Beanwah geesh... wish Rxjs didn't change like the wind though, fromPromise, from, Observable.from, just from by itself... make your minds up >.<

Answer (score 20):

Change

```
import { Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable'
import 'rxjs/observable/from'
```

To

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/from';
```

Comment: Bingo!!! Thanks alot @Sajeetharan.

Is there any official documentation which tells the exact tree to locate the correct imports for operators  and observable functions ?

Comment: I figured that out. Just pressing F12 on the "rxjs" can show the relevant import paths.

Comment: sorry i did not notice your comment, if you are using vscode, it shows too

Comment: now it says: `Module '"G:/learning-rxjs/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"' has no exported member 'Observable'.`

Comment: Then I get error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs'.

Comment: ERROR in ./src/app/services/auth-guard.service.ts
Module not found: Error: Recursion in resolving