# Property 'from' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable', angular 6?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular6

I updated my angular 5.2.10 project to angular 6.
I did step by step `https://update.angular.io/`, everything is OK unless `Observable.from`
In a service I used `Observable.from(this.user)` as following:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
...
Observable.from(this.users)// this.users is an array
```

It was OK, but in angular 6 the following error occurred

```
Property 'from' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'
```

I changed it as follows

```
import { Observable, from } from 'rxjs';
```

But no change and error occurred again!

Comment: you can also fix these upgrade issues using a TSLint rules for RxJs: `npm i -g rxjs-tslint` `rxjs-5-to-6-migrate -p tsconfig.json`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In **rxjs@6** you can use `from` as standalone function:

```
import { from } from 'rxjs';
...

from(this.users);
```

or

```
import { from as observableFrom } from 'rxjs';
...

observableFrom(this.users);
```

See also migration to rxjs6 guide

- https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md#import-paths

Comment: just out of curiosity, is not the same? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47003112/error-message-property-from-does-not-exist-on-type-typeof-observable

Comment: @Sajeetharan No, it's about rxjs6

Answer (score 3):

Without modifying the existing code, still you will be able to run just by installing "rxjs-compat" package.

```
npm install rxjs-compat --save
```

Comment: can you tell which folder? project or node_modules?

Comment: Just install from the root of the project.

Answer (score 3):

This is changed from previous rxjs versions to rxjs6. ([RxJS v5.x to v6 Update Guide](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md))

Before rxjs 6

```
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

let numbers = [1, 5, 10];
let source = Observable.from(numbers);
```

With [rxjs 6](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/from.html)

```
import { from, Observable } from "rxjs";

let numbers = [1, 5, 10];
let source = from(numbers);
```