# Why can't I import and use the 'of' value in Angular 5. The other questions/answers didn't work

Tags: angular, angular6

Yes this question has been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50257330/property-of-does-not-exist-on-type-typeof-observable). It claimed it was a repeat of [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50186371/property-from-does-not-exist-on-type-typeof-observable-angular-6) I tried to do all the things they said to do for the 'from' but for 'of' and I still got errors. Because I am still new to do this I don't have a 50 reputation to comment so I am asking it again because I didn't get an answer that works. I am working on the hero tutorial on angular.io but I am trying to do it with the newest version of Angular. One way or another I am going to learn the concepts of building angular node full stack apps so please help.

Comment: Are you using @angular/cli?

Comment: `import { of } from 'rxjs'; const ofStream$ = of('x');`

Comment: Yes, I am using @angular/cli. I am doing the Angular Heroes tutorial to get practice and better understand angular. I will also build node/express/mongodb API. Then I will do other angular tutorials and build APIs for them. This way I can really learn the MEAN stack well.

Comment: import { of } from 'rxjs';
const ofStream$ = of('x');

errors:
[tslint] This import is blacklisted, import a submodule instead (import-blacklist) 

[ts] Module"/Users.../rxjs/Rx" has no exported member 'of'.

Comment: @yurzui Let me know if I am doing it right. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

This is how I imported 'of'.

```
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
```

Then I was able to use it. You have put in a path that goes right to the javascript file that you want to use.

Comment: Are you sure you use angular6?

Comment: I thought it was because I had updated the cli to the latest version after 6 came out but no it still 5.2 according to the package.json.