# Angular6 Property 'debounceTime' does not exist on type 'Observable<any>'?

Tags: angular, rxjs

After updating my Angular 5 project into  Angular 6 following [Angular update guide](https://update.angular.io/)  i'm getting.

```
Property 'debounceTime' does not exist on type 'Observable<any>'
```

after running `ng update` my all components lost the `debounceTime import`. But i put it back manually but that didn't fixed the issue.

**example.component.ts**

```
import { debounceTime } from 'rxjs/operators';
 //Added after removed by ng update

 this.searchField.valueChanges
  .debounceTime(800)
  .distinctUntilChanged()
  .subscribe(term => {
    this.searchText = term;
    this.getAllDoctors();
  },
```

I really want to understand whats going on here.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/rx-library#operators. You missed the step "Remove deprecated RxJS 6 features using rxjs-tslint auto update rules.". If you're doing this step, and don't use an old library still using the old RxJS syntax, you don't need rxjs-compat.

Comment: Then **read** the documentation I linked to, and describing the syntax for applying operators.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You need to use pipe operator.

```
this.searchField.valueChanges
  .pipe(debounceTime(800),
        distinctUntilChanged()
   )
  .subscribe(term => {
    this.searchText = term;
    this.getAllDoctors();
  }),
```

Comment: @DayOne the code in this wanswer is correct. If it doesn't work for you, then post the actual code you tried in your question, and tell precisely **how** it didn't work. What do you expect to happen, and what happens instead, precisely.