# RxJS updated, Property 'merge' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

I updated my material angular project to include an expandable detail row in my table. I needed to upgrade to rsjx 6 for this. Now I get the following error. I'm totally new with angular, so unfortunately I don't have a clue how to resolve this.

```
Property 'merge' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'.
```

Can anyone help to resolve this error?

**app.component.ts**

```js
  /** Connect function called by the table to retrieve one stream containing the data to render. */
  connect(): Observable<Track[]> {
    // Listen for any changes in the base data, sorting, filtering, or pagination
    const displayDataChanges = [
    this._exampleDatabase.dataChange,
    this._sort.sortChange,
    this._filterChange,
    this._paginator.page
    ];

    this._exampleDatabase.getAllTracks();

    return Observable.merge(...displayDataChanges).map(() => {
      // Filter data
      this.filteredData = this._exampleDatabase.data.slice().filter((track: Track) => {
        const searchStr = (track.id + track.title + track.artist + track.year + track.comment + track.path).toLowerCase();
        return searchStr.indexOf(this.filter.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
      });

      // Sort filtered data
      const sortedData = this.sortData(this.filteredData.slice());

      // Grab the page's slice of the filtered sorted data.
      const startIndex = this._paginator.pageIndex * this._paginator.pageSize;
      this.renderedData = sortedData.splice(startIndex, this._paginator.pageSize);
      return this.renderedData;
    });
  }
```

Comment: do you have rxjs-compat package installed?

Comment: See this: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md

Comment: Same for other properties like ["Property `'from'` does not exist..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47003112/error-message-property-from-does-not-exist-on-type-typeof-observable)

Comment: And also; ["Property `'debounceTIme'` does not exist...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51917433/angular6-property-debouncetime-does-not-exist-on-type-observableany/51917462)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Static `merge` is imported as the following since version 6:

```
import {merge} from 'rxjs'
```

Then use it as:

```
merge(...)
```

Answer (score 4):

in old version of `rxjs` you use `Observable.merge(...array).map(() => {});`.
for new versions i.e **rxjs 6+** you have to use following syntax:

```
import { merge } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

merge(...array).pipe(
  map(...),
  ...
);
```